# warning: unknown conversion type character ‘"’ in format when using dprintf

Tags: c

I am getting this compiler (gcc 4.5) warning:

```
Formatter.cpp:23: warning: unknown conversion type character ‘"’ in format
```

And this is my code at line 23:

```
dprintf (fd, "<svg width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" version=\"1.1\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\">");
```

Can somebody spot what am I doing wrong and what causes the warning ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to escape all occurences of `%` - the printf family of function treats them as format specifiers and tries to parse the next character (for instance as in `%s`). You escape them by doubling (`%%`).